# How to initialize an array with an iterator in Rust?

Tags: arrays, syntax, rust, iterator

I am learning Rust and I find that it does not allow variables to be left uninitialized when they are declared. Question is, I am trying to load input into an array but I don't want to initialize it because the size of the array may be rather large and I think initializing it with some temp value is not good. Currently, this piece of code does not pass the compilation:

```rust
let mut height: [u8; maxn];
let mut i = 1; // I want to start from 1, not 0, but this is not the main problem.
while i <= n {
    height[i] = s_it.next().unwrap().parse().unwrap();
    i += 1;
}
```

So, is there any way I can use?

Comment: If the vector is large enough that you wouldn't want to 0-initialize it, you probably don't want it on the stack anyway: Use `Vec`.

Comment: Also "it does not allow variables to be left uninitialized when they are declared" is not true. It's perfectly fine not to initialize a variable as long as the compiler can prove that it has always been initialized once before reading it. This is similar to, eg. how C# treats variables and is definitely not just a Rust thing.